# "Unable to get Flow Instance Id and or subflow Id to manage the step." when trying to move to next step in APEX Flow

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to Flows for Apex trying to learn how it works. I made the tutorial and everything works fine until i tried to use it on my own example application. For that purpose I created the following process flow diagram:
[Flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htgqH.png)

First I need to activate the reservation. For that purpose, following the tutorial I created 2 processes, one to Create and Start the flow instance, and another one to move to the next step in the process flow exactly as instructed in the tutorial document. However, when I try to activate the reservation (executing the current process flow step), I get the error "Unable to get Flow Instance Id and or subflow Id to manage the step.". I also noticed that the SUBFLOW_ID variable is not set in the session state and I think this is the reason it doesn't want to move forward to the next step.

So my question is: how do I fix this error? If it doesn't want to work due to the SUBFLOW_ID not assigned, how do I assign value to it?

Comment: Flows for apex is not part of the official APEX product. It was created by another [company](https://flowsforapex.org/). I would reach out to them since this is an off-topic question for stack overflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about 3rd party software

Comment: @KoenLostrie I have nowhere else to ask. I tried to make a separate tag for it, but it didn't allow me to because I don't have 1500 reputation points. Also, someone else might know how to fix this issue, so why not try to ask here?...

Comment: If you go to https://flowsforapex.org/ and scroll down to the bottom there is a "Open Issue" button. This allows you to file an issue in Git. If it is a bug it should be picked up.